# macros error called object ‘x2’ is not a function

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to code simple macros which gives max number But I am getting error not able 
to figure out why

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX ((x1) ,(x2)) \
        ((x1) > (x2) ? (x1) : (x2)) 


int main () {

        int x1 = 10 ;
        int x2 =20 ;
        int j = MAX(x1 , x2) ;
        printf ("%d" , j) ;

}
```

called object ‘x2’ is not a function

Comment: Why have you written MAX ((x1) ,(x2)) as opposed to MAX(x1,x2) ?

Answer (score 3):

Your current macro produces a line that looks like:

```
int j = ((x1) ,(x2)) ((x1) > (x2) ? (x1) : (x2))(x1 , x2) ;
```

Let's fix your macro by writing it like this:

```
#define MAX(x1, x2) \
    ((x1) > (x2) ? (x1) : (x2))
```

This produces a line of code that looks like:

```
int j = ((x1) > (x2) ? (x1) : (x2)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of space between the `MAX` and `((x1) ,(x2))` is what creating your problem. it considers the replace MAX with whatever is following it when it encounters the space.

[Check this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments)
 this explains a similar example like yours.